# org mode to dokuwiki converter

Tags: emacs, conversion, dokuwiki

Is there an emacs org-mode to dokuwiki converter? Is there an dokuwiki to emacs org-mode converter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was just looking for the same thing, found this question here, and also found a [solution](https://gist.github.com/2005868) in the form of a Perl script on GitHub.

#### script

```
#!/opt/local/bin/perl
#
# Modified by @takaxp
# Last Update: 2012-01-09@22:13
# 2012-01-09: support date([YYYY-MM-DD XX]) insertion
# 2012-01-09: support #+BEGIN_SRC
# 2011-11-16: use strict and warnings
# 2011-11-16: Add conversion from numeric items to `  - '.
# 2011-11-16: Skip headers, if #+TITLE: is, use it as the top headline.
# 2011-11-17: Add DISQUS comment
# 2011-11-30: Add TODO/DONE color in items
# cat hoge.org | perl org2doku.pl > title.txt

# Usage
# 
#   cat <<EOF | ./org2doku
#   * heading
#   
#     - item
#       - sub item
#   
#   ** sub heading
#   EOF           
#   ===== heading =====
#   
#     * item
#       * sub item
#   
#   ==== sub heading ====
#
# Todo
#
#   * font style
# 
# Copyright
#
#   Copyright (c) 2011 Takumi KINJO
#
# License
#
#   The MIT License. See http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
#

use strict;
use warnings;

sub next_item_level {
    my ($len, $level, $last_item_indents) = @_;
    my $index = $#$last_item_indents;
    if ($index >= 0) {
        if ($len == $$last_item_indents[$index]) {
            return $level;
        } else {
            for (my $i = $index; $i >= 0; $i--) {
                my $last_item_indent = $$last_item_indents[$i];
                if ($len > $last_item_indent) {
                    push @$last_item_indents, $len;
                    return $level + 1;
                } elsif ($len == $last_item_indent) {
                    return $level - ($index - $i);
                }
                pop @$last_item_indents;
            }
            return $level;
        }
    } else {
        push @$last_item_indents, $len;
        return $level + 1;
    }
}

sub doku_link {
    my $org_hlink = shift;
    while ($org_hlink =~ s/\[\[(.*?)\]\[(.*?)\]\]/[[$1|$2]]/g) {}
    return $org_hlink;
}

sub shallowest_indent {
    my $last_item_indents = shift;
    my $shallowest_indent = 128;
    foreach my $code_line (@$last_item_indents) {
        if ($code_line =~ /^(\s+).*/) {
            my $len = length($1);
            if ($len < $shallowest_indent) {
                $shallowest_indent = $len;
            }
        } else {
            $shallowest_indent = 0;
        }
    }
    return $shallowest_indent;
}

sub disqus_comment {
    my $title_of_document = shift;
    if($title_of_document){
    print "===== Comments =====\n";
    }else{
    print "====== Comments ======\n";
    }
    print "~~DISQUS~~\n";
}

# Replace TODO in items with colored TODO
sub replace_todo_color {
    my $line = shift;
    $$line =~
    s/TODO/<html><span style="color: red">TODO<\/span><\/html>/;
    $$line =~
    s/DONE/<html><span style="color: ForestGreen">DONE<\/span><\/html>/;
}

my $is_code_block = 0;
my $is_published = 1;
my $is_table = 0;
my $current_block_type = "";
my $item_level = 0;
my $last_head_indent = 0;
my @code_block_buf = ();
my @last_item_indents = ();
my $title_of_document = "";
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my $line = $_;

    # skip headers
    if($line =~ /^#\+([^\s]+):\s*(.+)/){
    if($1 eq "TITLE"){
        $title_of_document = $2;
        print "====== ".$title_of_document." ======\n";
    }
    next;
    }

    # Replace TAB at the head of lines
    $line =~ s/^\t/<html>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<\/html>/;

    if($line =~ /^\[\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d/){
    $line =
        "<html><span style=\"color: #666666\">Date: ".$line."<\/span><\/html>\n";
    }

    # use github style
    $line =~ s/\=(.+?)\=/<html><span style=\"margin:0 2px;padding:2px 5px;white-space:nowrap;border:1px solid #ccc;background-color:#f8f8f8;border-radius:3px;-moz-border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;\">$1<\/span><\/html>/g;

  retry:
    if ($is_published) {
        if (/^=\ (.*)/) {
            # howm header
            $line = $1;
            $line =~ s/<<<//g;
            $line =~ s/^/====== /g;
            $line =~ s/$/ ======/g;
            $item_level = 0;
            @last_item_indents = ();

        } elsif (/^(\*+)\ (.*)/) {
            # org heading
            $last_head_indent = length($1);
            if ($2 =~ /^!/) {
                $is_published = 0;
                next;
            }
        my $max_headline = 6;
        if($title_of_document eq ""){
        $max_headline = 7;
        }
        my $doku_heading = ("=" x ($max_headline - length($1)));
            $line = $doku_heading." $2 ".$doku_heading;
            $item_level = 0;
            @last_item_indents = ();

        } elsif (/^(\s+)[-+*]\ (.*)/) {
            # org item
            $item_level =
        &next_item_level(length($1), $item_level, \@last_item_indents);
        my $content = $2;
        &replace_todo_color(\$content);
            $line = ("  " x $item_level)."* ".$content;

        } elsif (/^\s*(\d+)\.\s*(.+)$/) {
        # numerical item
        $line = "  - ".$2;
            $item_level = 0;
            @last_item_indents = ();

    } elsif (/^#\+begin_src\s(.+)$|#\+begin_example(.*)/i) {
        my $lang = $1;
        my $option = "";
        if($lang =~ /(.+?)\s(.+)$/){
        $lang = $1;
        $option = $2;
        }
        if($lang eq "emacs-lisp"){
        $current_block_type = "lisp";
        }else{
        $current_block_type = $lang;
        }
            # org code block begin
            $item_level = 0;
            @last_item_indents = ();
            $is_code_block = 1;
            next;

        } elsif (/^#\+end_src|^#\+end_example/i) {
            # org code block end
            $item_level = 0;
            @last_item_indents = ();
            $is_code_block = 0;
            print "<code ".$current_block_type.">\n";
            my $shallowest_indent = &shallowest_indent(\@code_block_buf);
            foreach my $line (@code_block_buf) {
                my $regex = "\ " x $shallowest_indent;
                $line =~ s/^$regex//g;
                $line =~ s/^,\*/*/g;
                print $line."\n";
            }
            print "</code>\n";
            @code_block_buf = ();
            next;

        } else {
            # paragraph
            if (!$is_code_block) {
                if ($line =~ /(.*?)\ \*([^\s]+)\*\ (.*)/) {
                    # bold
                    $line = $1." **".$2."** ".$3;
                }
                if ($line =~ /(.*?)\ _([^\s]+)_\ (.*)/) {
                    # under line
                    $line = $1." __".$2."__ ".$3;
                }

        # table
        if($line =~ /[^\|]*\|--/){
            $line = "";
            chomp($line);
        }elsif($line =~ /[^\|]*|/){
            $line =~ s/\|/\^/g;
        }else{
            $line = "?";
        }

            }
            $line =~ s/^\s+//g;
            if ($line) {
                $item_level = 0;
                @last_item_indents = ();
            }
        }

        if ($is_code_block) {
            push @code_block_buf, $_;
        } else {
            print &doku_link($line)."\n";
        }

    } else {
        if (/^(\*+)\ (.*)/) {
            my $head_indent = length($1);
            if (!($2 =~ /^!/)) {
                if ($head_indent <= $last_head_indent) {
                    $is_published = 1;
                    goto retry;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

&disqus_comment($title_of_document);
1;
```

I've tried converting a short Org document and it went well.

Comment: That script handles only bold and underline and one per line. You cannot have them first or last on the line.

Answer (score 4):

I needed the same and have put together export backend, for org-mode 8.0 and above https://github.com/w-vi/ox-wk.el , it's not 100% ready yet but major stuff should work.

Answer (score 3):

The [generic exporter](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-export-generic.html) could be easily configured to export to dokuwiki.  But I can't answer the "back" question.  Very little converts *to* org at this point.

Answer (score 1):

[Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/): `If you need to convert files from one markup format into another, pandoc is your swiss-army knife.`
It's easy to use and supports lots of different formats.